# the seconds button not work well in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use two-button to set the index value, once I click it gave value to the index.

```
public class tabbar : MonoBehaviour
{
   private int index = 0;
   public int buttonindex;
   public GameObject[] pannels;
   

   // Update is called once per frame
   void Update()
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < pannels.Length; i++)
       {
           if (i == index)
           {
               pannels[i].SetActive(true);
           }
           else
           {
               pannels[i].SetActive(false);
           }
       }
   }

   public void IWasClicked()
   {
       index = buttonindex;

   }

}
```

the first one is ok to set 0,but the second one no work??
any ideas?

Comment: Where is `buttonindex` ever set to a value other than 0?

Comment: It is quite unnecessary to add for loop in Update(), it is a bad practice. Why do not you add it to your ```IWasClicked()``` function after you have set your index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and don't forget to update your `buttonIndex`:

```cs
public class tabbar : MonoBehaviour
{
   public int buttonIndex;
   public GameObject[] pannels;

   private void UpdatePannels(int index)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < pannels.Length; i++)
       {
           pannels[i].SetActive(i == index);
       }
   }

   public void IWasClicked()
   {
       UpdatePannels(buttonIndex);
   }

}
```